# Calling a function with multiple arguments in ethers returns Error: missing argument

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, ethers.js, react, abi

I'm changing a part of front-end for my dApp from using `Moralis` to using `ethers.js`. For some reason I cannot get my head around on how to provide multiple arguments for the function call in a correct manner.

Consider this contract function that does on-chain conversion, using an oracle:

```
    function getUniversalConversionRate(uint256 coinAmount,address priceFeedAddress) 
    public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 coinPrice = getUniversalPrice(priceFeedAddress);
        uint256 coinAmountInUsdCents = (coinPrice * coinAmount) /10000000000000000;
        return coinAmountInUsdCents;}
```

This is its ABI:

```json
    {
        "inputs": [
            {"internalType": "uint256","name": "coinAmount","type": "uint256"},
            {"internalType": "address","name": "priceFeedAddress","type": "address"}],
        "name": "getUniversalConversionRate",
        "outputs": [{"internalType": "uint256","name": "","type": "uint256"}],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"},
```

And this is how I interact with it:

```
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://rpc...", 80001);
  const signer = new ethers.Wallet("0x...", provider); //saving space
  const administrativeSidechainContract = new ethers.Contract(mainContractAddress, abi, signer)
  
  async function updateUI() {
  const ethPriceData = await administrativeSidechainContract.getUniversalConversionRate({
       coinAmount: "1", priceFeedAddress: "0x...." })
  console.log(ethPriceData)}
  updateUI()
```

I provide both arguments which are correct and work in another framework with the same inputs but with `ethers` i get `Error: missing argument: passed to contract (count=1, expectedCount=2, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.6.0)`
What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass parameters like this:

```
const ethPriceData = await administrativeSidechainContract.getUniversalConversionRate("1", "0x....")
```

If you want to send ether, set gasLimit etc along with the function call, you can do like this:

```
const ethPriceData = await administrativeSidechainContract.getUniversalConversionRate("1", "0x....", {value: 100000000000})
```